# arecord flac format

Tags: sound, bash

I am playing with scripts that use the google speech-to-text api. The api requires flac encoded files so the recording part of the script looks like this:

```
arecord -q -t wav -d 0 -f S16_LE -r 16000 | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -s -o "$TEMP_FILE"
```

This command will record until the user exits with ctrl-c and the wav recorded format should be piped to the flac program for outut in flac format, then the script should continue.

The problem I am having is that pressing ctrl-c ends the script entirely and is cutting off some of the audio (the flac file is still outputted). If I run the script without the pipe:

```
arecord -q -t wav -d 0 -f S16_LE -r 16000 some.wav
```

Then pressing ctrl-c will only ends the recording and continues on with the script as it should.

How do I fix this so that ctrl-c only stops the arecord command and allows the rest of the script (including the piped flac encoding) to finish?

Comment: Try modifying the command to look like this `arecord -q -t wav -d 0 -f S16_LE -r 16000 | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -s -o "$TEMP_FILE" || true`

Comment: @Archuser: same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arecord` command has the -d argument to time it out with this modification the `arecord` command will time out but not the FLAC.

```
arecord -q -t wav -d 4 -f S16_LE -r 16000 | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -s -o "$TEMP_FILE"
```